# Bottom navigation icon color only changed after the second tap only.how to make on first tap?

Tags: android, android-layout

When I click bottom navigation icon the color of the icon is not changed.but if again I clicked it getting changed.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/btm_slctd_clr"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/btm_slctd_clr"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />`
```

//btm_slctd_clr

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_pressed" />
           <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/color_pressed"  />
    </selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage it with a boolean variable if you touch it for the first time make boolean variable true and aftertouch make boolean variable false and the whole process will proceed under the condition and set your background when your boolean variable has a false value.

Answer (score 0):

While making a selector, always keep the default state at the end, otherwise only default state would be used. You need to reorder the items in your selector as:

Change the color as per your requirement in
selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
<item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
</selector>
```

Add it on your layout file. Like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView 
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"/>
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Still not working.is any issue with java code reflect this?

Comment: Try this way: <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />`